# MySQL error: Cannot add foreign key constraint (PrestaShop module)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop, prestashop-modules

I'm trying to write MySQL queries for my custom PrestaShop module. I encountered an issue while adding foreign keys and have no idea what might be wrong. I double checked column types and their existance.

Here's the error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_pp_project` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_group` INT,
    `id_product` INT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    `height` INT,
    `width` INT,
    `file` VARCHAR(255),
    `class_name` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `' ._DB_PREFIX_. '
    product`(`id_product`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_group`) REFERENCES `' ._DB_PREFIX_. 
    'pp_group`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=' . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8mb4';
```

And here is all the code I'm trying to run during installation

```
    $sqls[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pp_group` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=' . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8mb4';

$sqls[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pp_project` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_group` INT,
    `id_product` INT(10),
    `name` VARCHAR(255),
    `height` INT,
    `width` INT,
    `file` VARCHAR(255),
    `class_name` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `' ._DB_PREFIX_. 'product`(`id_product`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_group`) REFERENCES `' ._DB_PREFIX_. 'pp_group`(`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=' . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8mb4';

$sqls[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pp_layer` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_project` INT,
    `label` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'Twój tekst\',
    `position_x` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `position_y` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `max_chars` INT DEFAULT 10,
    `text_align` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'left\',
    `height` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `width` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `placeholder` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'Tekst\',
    `rotation` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `skew_x` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `skew_y` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `color` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'000\',
    `font_family` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'arial\',
    `font_size` INT DEFAULT 12,
    `line_height` INT DEFAULT 12,
    `row_quantity` INT DEFAULT 1,
    `visible` BOOL DEFAULT 1,
    `layer_type` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'text\',
    `file` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT null,
    `opacity` FLOAT DEFAULT 1.0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_project`) REFERENCES `' ._DB_PREFIX_. 'pp_project`(`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=' . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . ' DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8mb4';


foreach ($sqls as $sql) {
    if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The queries execute perfectly without foreign keys.

> UPDATE

Found out that the issue is this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `' ._DB_PREFIX_. '
product`(`id_product`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

However, I haven't yet figured out how to fix it.

Comment: I would put the statements to add the keys in  separate queries and execute them after all the other statements.

Comment: Where is the query to create the `ps_product` table?

Comment: "Cannot add foreign key constraint" -> can you share the complete error? It could be the type of the key in the foreign table is not the same for example

Comment: @Barmar This table already exists, and is created during Prestashop instalation.

Comment: @GertB. I'm pretty sure that's the whole error -- MySQL is really sucky about this.

Comment: See https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/ for a list of all the reasons for this error.

Comment: @GertB. yup. Unfotunatelly prestashop is not elaborating it's errors. The rest of the error is in my mother tongue and quickly translating sounds like that: "An error occured in module *my module name* during installation. Cannot add foreign key constraint".

Comment: When you create the tables you're using a prefix as part of the table name. When you create the foreign key constraint you're not including the prefix.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular updated the code, but that one line that tries to create foreign key from table `ps_product` is still causing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

In the table `ps_product` column `id_product` is **UNSIGNED** and **NOT NULL**.

While creating table `ps_pp_project` I create column `id_product` without specifying those attributes

```
$sqls[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pp_project` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_group` INT,
`id_product` INT(10),
[...]
```

To solve the issue, the query should look like this:

```
$sqls[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pp_project` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_group` INT,
`id_product` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

At

```
FOREIGN KEY (`id_group`) REFERENCES `pp_group`(`id`)
```

check if pp_group table exists, maybe you may write ps_group or ps_pp_group instead.

Comment: Indeed here's a mistake, it should be `FOREIGN KEY (id_group) REFERENCES ' ._DB_PREFIX_. 'pp_group(id)`, however, it didn't solve the issue with foreign keys